# Apache problem on Mac

Tags: macos, apache

I couldn't visit 127.0.0.1 on my mac .  I turned on the "web share" already.

and there is no "httpd" process in Activity Monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "visit" I assume you mean using your browser.

Your browser tries to connect to a HTTP server. If you don't have httpd or some similar program running on your box then it's no wonder you can't reach it.

Solution: Install and configure a Web server.

Alternate solution: Clarify what you're trying to do, and why.

Comment: sorry for my poor english. your assume is right.
the problem is : in mac "open web share" means start the apache server.

Comment: Apache usually writes log files. On Unix systems these would be in /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd or something like that. On OS X, I don't know offhand. If the server failed to start you may find a clue in either an apache log or a system log.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Terminal (/Applications/Utilities), and then try to start apache from the command line.

Try this to help debug: 
sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k start

when it is dying silently. Also, check the error_log at: /var/log/apache2/error_log

You can use TextEdit for the error_log, if you feel more comfortable with a GUI text editor.

Let me know how it goes!